# if choice == variable + variable is not working

Tags: ruby

I have a problem with this code, in the IF statement I am trying to join 2 variables as the result of the choice == 
I have tried to join with +, with && , inside (), but does not work.
Thank you in advance.

```
def justicia_room

 primera = "la sociedad"
 segunda = "sus integrantes"
 tercera = "marco adecuado"
 cuarta = "prohibiendo y permitiendo"


  puts """Es un valor determinado como bien común por
        #{primera}
          Nació de la necesidad de mantener la armonía entre
        #{segunda}.
         Es el conjunto de pautas y criterios que establecen un
        #{tercera}
         para las relaciones entre personas e instituciones, autorizando,
         #{cuarta}
        acciones específicas en la interacción de los mismos
         """



if  choice == primera && segunda
  puts choice.include?("s")
  puts "Hay algo escondido pero no con esta combinacion"

elsif choice == tercera
  #puts choice.concat ([6,8])
  puts "Encontraste los primeros numeros, Good job!"
else
puts "No es aceptable esa respuesta"
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby you concatenate two strings in many ways: `+` method, interpolation, specialized methods (`concat` method for example). Probably you simply did not put a space between your strings. Try

```
choice == primera + " " + segunda # + method
choice == "#{primera} #{segunda}" # interpolation
choice == primera.concat(" ").concat(segunda) # concat method
choice == [primera, seguenda].join(" ") # join method
```

Comment: as of `2.4` one can call `String#concat` with multiple objects e.g.  `primera.concat(" ",segunda)` :)